# Find job tags from Gitlab CI API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there a way of finding out what tags (Gitlab CI tags, not git tags) a job has from the API?

As background, we are having some issues with contention on our CI pipeline. The runners are selected based on tags, and I want to log what tags are being used/built the most.

For instance if in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I have

```
build_thing: 
  stage: build
  tags: [some_tag]
  script:
   - bash build.sh
```

Is there a way I can use the gitlab jobs API to determine show the tags (`some_tag`) of that job? I have not been able to find any API endpoints that show this in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html).

I am aware that I can look at what tags the active runners have, but unfortunately that is not enough information, as they can have different combinations of tags that overlap the jobs/pipelines.

Comment: This is missing from the API for sure - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/52141